# Is there a planar graph with 8 edges that has no plane drawing in which every finite region is convex?

Tags: graph-theory

convex: a region in a plane drawing of a planar graph is called convex if whenever any two points on the boundary of or in the region are connected by a straight line segment, the straight line segment lies entirely inside the region.

I tried many times but I cannot find such a graph. Is there any trick to draw such graph?

Comment: Can you draw $K_{2,4}$ in that way? That's the graph in which each of $a,b$ is joined to each of $w,x,y,z$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson wow you're right! Thank you!

Comment: If you can prove it, let me encourage you to write up your proof and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Every polyhedral planar graph has a [Tutte embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_embedding), where every face is convex.  But this doesn't apply if the graph is 2-connected.

Comment: So, this isn't actually an answer, more of a hint as to where to look for a counterexample, right?